# SQL Server Pivoting without calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, transpose

I want to pivot a table, I tried self-join but it is very slow.    kindly help me to do this.Below is my table structure.

```
STUDENT_ID   AC_YEAR    AC_TERM     STANDING      ENRL_TERM_SEQ 
10001         2015       SPRING        NULL           1          
10001         2015       FALL          NULL           2          
10001         2016       SPRING         W             3          
10001         2016       FALL           W             4          
10002         2015       SPRING        NULL           1          
10002         2015       FALL           W             2          
10002         2016       SPRING        NULL           3          
10002         2016       FALL          NULL           4          
10005         2015       SPRING        NULL           1          
10005         2015       FALL          NULL           2         
10005         2016       SPRING        NULL           3          
10005         2016       SUMMER        NULL           4          
10005         2016       FALL          NULL           5
```

I want to pivot this like below

```
ST_ID  CUR_YR  CUR_TM CUR_SD  PR1_YR  PR1_TM  PR1_SD  PR2_YR PR_TM  PR2_SD
10001  2016    FALL    W      2016    SPRING    W     2015    FALL   NULL
10002  2016    FALL   NULL    2016    SPRING   NULL   2015    FALL    W 
10005  2016    FALL   NULL    2016    SUMMER   NULL   2016   SPRING  NULL
```

Can I do this with Pivot?

Kindly note in the resultset, I changed the field name due to space limitation

Thanks in advance.

Can I get the rows like below?

```
ST_ID  CUR_YR  CUR_TM CUR_SD  PR1_YR  PR1_TM  PR1_SD  PR2_YR PR_TM  PR2_SD 
10001  2015    SPRING   NULL   NULL   NULL    NULL    NULL   NULL    NULL
10001  2015    FALL     NULL   2015   SPRING  NULL    NULL   NULL    NULL
10001  2016    SPRING    W     2015   FALL    NULL    2015   SPRING  NULL
10001  2016    FALL      W     2016   SPRING   W      2015   FALL    NULL
10002  2015    SPRING   NULL   NULL   NULL    NULL    NULL   NULL    NULL
10002  2015    FALL      W     2015   SPRING  NULL    NULL   NULL    NULL
10002  2016    SPRING   NULL   2015   FALL     W      2015   SPRING  NULL
10002  2016    FALL     NULL   2016   SPRING  NULL    2015   FALL     W
10005  2015    SPRING   NULL   NULL   NULL    NULL    NULL   NULL    NULL
10005  2015    FALL     NULL   2015   SPRING  NULL    NULL   NULL    NULL
10005  2016    SPRING   NULL   2015   FALL    NULL    2015   SPRING  NULL
10005  2016    SUMMER   NULL   2016   SPRING  NULL    2015   FALL    NULL
10005  2016    FALL     NULL   2016   SUMMER  NULL    2016   SPRING  NULL
```

Comment: What about the two 2015 entries for `10005` ID? Where are they in the output?

Comment: Hi Vashi, Thanks for the response.I need three previous term only so that will be ignored If we can get the full term it is better, I need to compare last three standing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will return last three terms. If you need more add extra columns and change `rn` value:

```
select
    STUDENT_ID
    , max(case when rn = 1 then AC_YEAR end), max(case when rn = 1 then AC_TERM end), max(case when rn = 1 then STANDING end)
    , max(case when rn = 2 then AC_YEAR end), max(case when rn = 2 then AC_TERM end), max(case when rn = 2 then STANDING end)
    , max(case when rn = 3 then AC_YEAR end), max(case when rn = 3 then AC_TERM end), max(case when rn = 3 then STANDING end)
from (
    select
        *, row_number() over (partition by STUDENT_ID order by AC_YEAR desc, case AC_TERM when 'FALL' then 1 when 'SUMMER' then 2 when 'SPRING' then 3 end) rn
    from
        myTable
) t
where
    rn <= 3
group by STUDENT_ID
```

Comment: HI, Thanks for the query, Summer is an option semester,it is not mandatory for students to enroll in that semster and some students will not enroll in the same sequence they may miss some semesters in between

Comment: The order is working, i have changed order by AC_YEAR to ENRL_TERM_SEQ

Comment: select
        *, row_number() over (partition by STUDENT_ID order by ENROLL_TERMSEQ desc) rn
    from
       myTABLE
) t
where
    rn <= 3
group by STUDENT_ID //Changed the query like this,it is working fine now thank you so much

Comment: Yes, it is better use `ENRL_TERM_SEQ` for ordering. i have not paid attention to that column when was writing query

Answer (score 1):

Take last three terms, based on `ENRL_TERM_SEQ` for respective students and pull required columns.

```
SELECT A.STUDENT_ID,

MAX(CASE WHEN A.TERM = 1 THEN A.AC_YEAR END) AS CUR_YR,
MAX(CASE WHEN A.TERM = 1 THEN A.AC_TERM END) AS CUR_TM,
MAX(CASE WHEN A.TERM = 1 THEN A.STANDING END) AS CUR_SD,

MAX(CASE WHEN A.TERM = 2 THEN A.AC_YEAR END) AS PR1_YR,
MAX(CASE WHEN A.TERM = 2 THEN A.AC_TERM END) AS PR1_TM,
MAX(CASE WHEN A.TERM = 2 THEN A.STANDING END) AS PR1_SD,

MAX(CASE WHEN A.TERM = 3 THEN A.AC_YEAR END) AS PR2_YR,
MAX(CASE WHEN A.TERM = 3 THEN A.AC_TERM END) AS PR2_YM,
MAX(CASE WHEN A.TERM = 3 THEN A.STANDING END) AS PR2_SD

FROM

(SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY STUDENT_ID ORDER BY ENRL_TERM_SEQ DESC) AS TERM FROM YOUR_TABLE) A

GROUP BY A.STUDENT_ID
ORDER BY A.STUDENT_ID;
```

Comment: Hi Vashi, Can you suggest a solution for this ( sorry my question attached as third answer)

Comment: What's the difference in the output from the previous one?